# TableViewCell(SubView) trigger button show segue to new view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

i have one **BUTTON** in tableviewcell which has Action Segue show to next view controller. And i have a **UIView** inside the tableviewcell as well.

[I wish to use the UIView(Green) Tap gesture action to trigger the button show segue action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBZOH.png)

Is there any guide for me to refer? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Why you want a view to trigger a button action? Or if I am wrong you want to segue after tapping on your view and changing the background color to green.??

Comment: @TusharSharma thanks for your comment. I have a default button setup that will be clicked to view next view controller. Therefore, i created a new UIView and wished to tap the gesture to perform the default button action.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to trigger `button action` to call segue, you can call it programmatically in `tap gesture action` using the below code.

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueId" sender:nil]`;

Answer (score 0):

In your tap gesture action, add this:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"YourSegueIdentifierInStoryboard", sender: yourButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it:
Declare a **protocol** for the cell including a callback function

```
func cellGreenButtonTouched(button:UIButton)
```

then implement this protocol in the tableViewController.
From there, you can just call: pushViewController() or performSegueWithIdentifier()

In order to have the touch on the green button to trigger the call, you'll have to bind the button (CTRL+drag from the button) to the cell's delegate local function

```
func greenButtonTouchedUpInside(...) {
  delegate?.cellGreenButtonTouched(button:button)
}
```

This should work perfectly well.